# How to read data from cloud firestore with firebase function and loop and push it to list

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read data from firestore collection to get notification token and push it to a list and pass the list to SendtoDevice function to send push notification.

I am facing issue when using foreach function and push the data getting error "for each is not a valid function"

```
let tokenList = [];

const userNotificationTokenDocs = await db.collection("userToken").doc(userId).get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
console.log(doc.data().Tokens);
tokenList.push(doc.data().Tokens);
});
return null;
});

**other option which i tried, with same error.**

userNotificationTokenDocs.forEach(function(docs){
   console.log(docs.data());
   if(docs.data() != null){
    tokenList.push(docs.data().Token);
   }
});
```

Please help me, I am stuck with this.

Comment: You are mixing `await` and `then` in the same statement.  That doesn't make any sense - just use one or the other. You might want to take a moment to review how Futures work in dart.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried without await still it's not pushing data to the list, and I checked twice querysnapshot it returning data.

Answer (score 1):

found some **BASIC** mistake in your coding.

- `const userNotificationTokenDocs` will always null , because you return null. forEach is void function.
- Using `await` and `then` is unecessery. choose 1.
- `=>` arrow is a shorthand for `{ return expr; }` .
  if you only have 1 expresion, you can shorthand with arrow. but if you have morethan 1 expression, just use bracket `{}` . [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions)
- `userNotificationTokenDocs.forEach(function(docs){` this will error since null value cant use forEach.

#### I think your IDE should give you alert there's an error in your code. but you choose to run it instead fixing the error.

but is ok, keep learning code. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am newbie, i am learning lot of from people like you. thanks. Could you please help me what's wrong with this. var userToken= await db.collection('Users')
                .doc(userId)
                .collection('Tokens')
                .get();      userToken.forEach(function(docs){
                if(docs.data() != null){
                    TokenList.push(docs.data().Token);
                }
            });

Comment: what current error you get?  
did you use any additional package? because List on dart doesnt support `push()` method.
if you want to add item to list , use `add()` method.  `tokenList.add(docs.data().Token`

Comment: This is firebase cloud function, i am getting list of usertoken to send push notification, to available users based on token

Comment: Error i am getting "TypeError: forEach is not a function"